# Do I need to encode the URL in order for Google App Script to work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have tried this very simple query with Postman and it returned the results I expected. However, when I tried to implement the code with App Script, it always returns an error:

> Exception: Invalid argument: (my url)

Postman (works with no issue)

```
curl --location -g --request GET 'https://app.jobnimbus.com/api1/tasks?filter={"must":[{"term":{"related.id":"lakd4sbguzoz9we65494zg0"}},{"term":{"related.type":"job"}}]}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer l8krtz11bch2m9mj'
```

App script (returns the exception "Invalid argument"  )

```
url = 'https://app.jobnimbus.com/api1/tasks?filter={"must":[{"term":{"related.id":"lakd4sbguzoz9we65494zg0"}},{"term":{"related.type":"job"}}]}'
  config = {
    'headers':{'Authorization':'Bearer token'},
  }
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, config)
```

I have tried with a url as simple as `https://app.jobnimbus.com/api1/tasks` and it returned expected results. However, when I tried to pass some queries such as `?filter={}` it started to throw errors. I then tried to encode the `?filter={}` query but it still returned

> Exception: Invalid argument

I also tried the examples provided by the documentation page (https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3919598/S11PpG4x?version=latest#6ecbf20e-173f-4542-bc2d-20c61f4e9805) and it worked with Postman. On the other hand, it did not work with App Script. Below are the example code for both platforms. I'm guess that my url is formatted badly. I would like you experts to give me a hint on how to modify or point out where to find the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl --location -g --request GET 'https://app.jobnimbus.com/api1/tasks?filter={"must":[{"term":{"related.id":"lakd4sbguzoz9we65494zg0"}},{"term":{"related.type":"job"}}]}' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer l8krtz11bch2m9mj'
  ```
- You have already confirmed that your curl command worked fine.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
url = 'https://app.jobnimbus.com/api1/tasks?filter={"must":[{"term":{"related.id":"lakd4sbguzoz9we65494zg0"}},{"term":{"related.type":"job"}}]}'
```

#### To:

```
const url = `https://app.jobnimbus.com/api1/tasks?filter=${encodeURIComponent('{"must":[{"term":{"related.id":"lakd4sbguzoz9we65494zg0"}},{"term":{"related.type":"job"}}]}')}`;
```

or

```
const url = `https://app.jobnimbus.com/api1/tasks?filter=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({ "must": [{ "term": { "related.id": "lakd4sbguzoz9we65494zg0" } }, { "term": { "related.type": "job" } }] }))}`;
```